# Passing a JSon object to a Marionette composite View

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, marionette

I have a simple table that shows a list of objects, however i want to pass a boolean so that if the user is logged in he can see the [edit] button, i have tried passing the parameter as a listItem but was unable to, can anyone shed a light onto this?

CLARIFICATION: I want to be able to access the value from inside the template

```
       var TableView = {};

    TableView.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        tagName: "tr",
        template:$('#table-template-item').html(),

        //if required add events and triggers here.
        events: {
            "click td a.js-show": "showClicked",
            "click td a.js-edit": "editClicked"
            }

       });

    TableView.MainTable = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        tagName: "table",
        className: "table table-hover",
        template: $('#table-template').html() ,
        itemView: TableView.RowItemView,
        itemViewContainer: "tbody"

    });

   return TableView;

    InitialController.home = function () {
    console.log("initializing application layout");
    var list = new PropertiesModel.ContactCollection;
    list.fetch({reset: true});
    var tableView = new TableView.MainTable({
        collection: list
    });

    app.mainRegion.show(tableView);

};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume there's some place in your application where you know whether the user is logged in or not. For the sake of argument I'll assume it's encapsulated in a function attached to a User object, which in turn is attached to the global App, so `MyApp.CurrentUser.isLoggedIn()`.

One approach you could take is to add a dependency between the `RowItemView` and this `CurrentUser` object. When you're rendering the `RowItemView` test if the user is logged in and update the view accordingly.

I'm making a lot of assumptions about your code here, but this snippet should demonstrate the basic idea:

```
  onRender: function() {
    if (MyApp.CurrentUser.isLoggedIn()) {
      this.$('.js-edit').removeClass('hidden');
    }
  }
```

*Addendum*

So, you want to update multiple sections of your view? Try using the templateHelpers property:

```
TableView.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

  template: /* resolves to: */ '<td><%= getItemOne() %></td>' +
                             '<td><%= getItemTwo() %></td>',
  templateHelpers: {
    getItemOne: function() {
        if (window.isLoggedIn) {
            return 'Logged In Content';
        }
        return 'Not Logged In Content';
    },
    getItemTwo: function() {
        if (window.isLoggedIn) {
            return 'Logged In Content';
        }
        return 'Not Logged In Content';
    }
}
```

Since you say `isLoggedIn` is in the global namespace there's no need to pass it in. If you need to pass it in though, try:

```
TableView.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  initialize: function(options) {
    this.templateHelpers.isLoggedIn = options.isLoggedIn;
    // ... other work as needed
  },
  templateHelpers: {
    getItemOne: function() {
        if (this.isLoggedIn) {} // should work now
    }
  }
```

The problem with this approach is that you're passing a variable from a CompositeView, which means you need to override the CompositeView's `buildItemView` property, which frankly seems like more work than its worth, but here's a snippit if you want to try it:

```
TableView.MainTable = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  initialize: function(collection, options) {
    this.isLoggedIn = options.isLoggedIn;
    // ...
  },
  buildItemView: function(item, ItemViewType, itemViewOptions){
    var options = _.extend({model: item, isLoggedIn: this.isLoggedIn }, itemViewOptions);
    return new ItemViewType(options);
  },
```

Comment: Hello chris, yes, I have a global variable that states if the user is logged in or not, the problem is i want to have a template that has a few <%= isLogged%> statements, however i pass my model to the rowItemView, so I do not know how to pass my user object to it.

Comment: Ah. Have you tried using `templateHelpers`? I'll update my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can supply `ItemViewOptions` as either a function (dynamic) or an object (static) to each of the itemviews that are rendered out by your composite/collection view

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md#collectionviews-itemviewoptions

```
TableView.MainTable = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    itemViewOptions: function(){
        return {
            isLoggedIn: //true/false
        };
    },
    //snip...
}
```

Once set in the `CollectionView`/`CompositeView` then you can grab them by doing the following in your `ItemView`:

```
initialize: function(options){
    var x = options.isLoggedIn;
}
```

EDIT: Or, to see it in the template `<%=isLoggedIn%>`

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.model.set('isLoggedIn', options.isLoggedIn || false);
}
```

Comment: Hello Scott, I had tried something like that, the problem is that I cant pass that value to my template, when i try to access isLogged on the template i get the error message that it is undefined.

Comment: You will need to put the `isLoggedIn` variable into the model for it to be read by the template engine (`this.model.set('isLoggedIn', options.isLoggedIn || false)`). If that's the case, then you might want to do that in the `CompositeView`/`CollectionView` and just forgo the itemViewOptions. Up to you!

Comment: Furthermore, Marionette has inbuilt functionality to handle the template by just being provided with a string. So instead of writing `template: $('#table-template').html()` you only need to write `template: #table-template'`

Comment: I'd argue against adding an `isLoggedIn` attribute to the model as it could break separation of concerns - e.g. if the model describes a product, it doesn't really make sense for the `Product` model to know whether the user is logged in. This is why Marionette views support `templateHelpers`.

Comment: Scott thank you very much for your help, but I agree with chris, expecially if I am already using the model for something else.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like every row will either be editable or non-editable. So heres another answer that I think is more appropriate for your needs. It will prevent you having to pass an option and executing logic in *every* `ItemView`, but will involve having to have another view type

```
TableView.RowItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:'#table-template-item',
    //...snip
});

TableView.EditableRowItemView = TableView.RowItemView.extend({
    template:'#editable-table-template-item',
});

TableView.MainTable = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        if(isLoggedIn){ //true/false
            this.itemView = TableView.EditableRowItemView
        }
    },
    itemView: TableView.RowItemView
}
```

The `EditableRowItemView` extends from `TableView.RowItemView` as they will have largely the same logic, but with different templates (and maybe some extra editing logic)

Comment: While it's not imminently clear in the question, the OP explained in his comments he's looking to conditionally insert items in each `ItemView` based on whether the user is logged in.